# Secure use of shutil.rmtree / os.path.join and Directory Traversal

Tags: python, security, path, escaping, shutil

I have a predefined path which is concatenated with a userinput to delete a specific directory. The current code looks like this, and given such a userinput will harm very badly:

```
import os
import shutil
userinput = '../../'
path = os.path.join('/my/self/defined/path', userinput)
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

This will obviously allow the user to delete any files or directories. What is a good way to “jail” the user, so it will only be possible to enter any path below `/my/self/defined/path`, taking care of `../` or starting the string with `/` and all other malicious input I might not think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
my = os.path.abspath('/my/self/defined/path')
new = os.path.abspath(path)
if len(new) < len(my) or not new.startswith(my):
   print 'bzzzt'
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: That would prevent deleting for example `/my/self/`, but if the user enters `../../some/where/else`, he might get to a directory outside of the defined path which could be also longer than the original one. Better than no filtering of course, but still too dangerous.

Comment: In that case, it would trip the new.startswith(my) test.

Comment: Oh, I wonder how I could miss reading the second condition, sorry. But the check for the length can be left out completely, couldn’t it? Also, I wonder if `realpath` or `abspath` should be preferred.

Comment: The length check could be eliminated.

Comment: wrap abspath in os.path.normpath() to remove things like ../. realpath is good, but you'll also want to call it on '/my/self/defined/path' in case its symlinked.

Comment: @tdelaney  abspath: "On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))." Why call normpath again?  Don't I already call it on '/my/self/defined/path'?  Perhaps I misunderstand your comment.

Comment: @foosion - Interesting. The inline help for abspath is rather terse and I always assumed that you'd need normpath if you wanted to make it canonical. If abspath is already doing that, then it would indeed be a waste to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
userinput = '../../'
selfdefinedpath = '/my/self/defined/path'
path = os.path.join(selfdefinedpath, userinput)
if not selfdefinedpath in os.path.realpath(path):
  print 'not proper path %s' % path
  sys.exit()
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

Comment: I would replace `selfdefinedpath in os.path.realpath(path)` with `os.path.realpath(path).startswith(selfdefinedpath)`, otherwise `/some/where/my/self/defined/path/foo/bar` could be deleted (although it is pretty unlikely). Otherwise the solution seems pretty solid to me, but I will wait a bit before setting it to accepted, maybe someone else finds another issue.

Comment: Yes you are wright it is highly unlikely some one will provide such input, but never take chances specially if security is the main concern.